# append html outside of the parent tag using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

So I have this scenario

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    <div id="list">Hello</div>
</div>
```

I want to call

```
var html = $('<div id="replaced" contenteditable="false">Hello</div>');
$('#list').replaceWith(html);
```

The problem is I want the output to be like this:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    <div id="replaced" contenteditable="false">Hello</div><br />
</div>
```

I tried the following and it didn't work: (Where this is the div replacing tmp.mention)

```
$('#'+tmp.mention).replaceWith(this).parent().after('<br />');
```

I want to do this because the div replacing tmp.mention has contenteditable set to false inside a div editor that has a contenteditable set to true. If there's no 
 the user will not be able to type after the div...

Comment: Your requirement is a little confusing to me! You call `var html=..` and it doesn't have a `contenteditabe=false` in there. And then I don't see how the last code snippet adds into all of this. Maybe you could put something on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#'+tmp.mention).replaceWith($(this).parent()).after('<br />');
```

I think you need

```
var html = $('<div id="replaced" contenteditable=false>Hello</div>');
$('#list').replaceWith(html);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hSZqe/)

But if you want to whole `#editor` then

```
var html = $('<div id="replaced" contenteditable=false>Hello</div>');
$('#list').parent().replaceWith(html);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Us5pV/)**

#### According to edit

If you want output like

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    <div id="replaced" contenteditable="false">Hello</div><br />
</div
```

then try

```
var html = $('<div id="replaced" contenteditable=false>Hello</div>');
$('#list').replaceWith(html).after('</br>');
```

Comment: That won't work because $(this).parent() will actually return the container of a list of suggestions - $(this) being a single suggestion.

Comment: Actually I confused you, I shouldn't be using that example, it was straight from my code. this refers to a clicked element, that clicked element comes from a tooltip that is outside the editor.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#list').replaceWith('<div id="replaced" contenteditable="false">Hello</div><br />')
```